# Why is the efficiency of my neural network code reducing and what is causing the issue?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, training-data

I am trying to implement a simple neural network from scratch to classify images from the MNIST dataset. However, I have noticed that the efficiency of the code decreases as I try to train the network on a larger number of examples. Specifically, the performance of the function train_dataset() is problematic. I have gone through the code and think that the issue lies with the variables sum_d_a and sum_d that are initialized and updated in the for-loop inside train_dataset(). Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
def train_dataset(train_images, train_labels, activations, w, lr):
    m = len(train_images)
    deltas = [] # has deltas array for each training sample (yeah deltas in deltas)

    # getting deltas for each training sample
    for i in range(m):
        deltas.append(train_example(train_images[i], activations, w, train_labels[i]))

    # gradient descent
    for l in [3, 2, 1]:
        sum_d_a = np.zeros((w[0][l-1].shape)) 
        sum_d = np.zeros(w[1][l-1].shape)

        ####################### FINDING SUMS #####################################
        for i in range(m):  # for each training example
            sum_d_a += np.matmul(deltas[i][l-1], activations[l-1].T)
            sum_d += deltas[i][l-1]

        w[0][l-1] += lr * sum_d_a / m
        w[1][l-1] += lr * sum_d / m
```

I am not sure if this is the only part that is causing the inefficiency, but I have profiled the code and found that this loop takes a long time to execute. Could someone help me understand what is happening here and how I can fix it?

The whole code just in case:

```
import idx2numpy
import numpy as np

# utils
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_prime(x):
    return sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x))

# Get data
train_images = idx2numpy.convert_from_file("data/train-images.idx3-ubyte")
train_labels = idx2numpy.convert_from_file("data/train-labels.idx1-ubyte")
test_images = idx2numpy.convert_from_file("data/test-images.idx3-ubyte")
test_labels = idx2numpy.convert_from_file("data/test-labels.idx1-ubyte")

train_images = np.reshape(train_images, (train_images.shape[0], -1)) / 255
train_labels = np.reshape(train_labels, (train_labels.shape[0], -1))
test_images = np.reshape(test_images, (test_images.shape[0], -1)) / 255
test_labels = np.reshape(test_labels, (test_labels.shape[0], -1))

# initialises variables: "activations" and "w"
def init_vars():
    activations = [
        np.zeros((784,1)),# input layer
        np.zeros((16,1)), # hidden layer 1
        np.zeros((16,1)), # hidden layer 2
        np.zeros((10,1))  # output layer
    ]

    w_01 = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(16,784))
    w_12 = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(16,16))
    w_23 = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(10,16))

    b_1 = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(16,1))
    b_2 = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(16,1))
    b_3 = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(10,1))

    w = [
        [w_01, w_12, w_23], 
        [b_1, b_2, b_3]
    ]

    return activations, w

# train NN
def train_example(input_layer, activations, w, ideal_output):
    """
    For each training example, we must go through each of the following steps:
    1. Feedforward: 
        - find z and a for each layer (layer indices: 1, 2, 3)
    2. Output error:
        - delta for last layer (the output layer)
    3. Backpropogate the error:
        - find delta for each layer with layer indices: 2, 1
    """
    
    # activations array has 3 elements, each is a layer's activation values
    activations[0] = input_layer  
    activations[0] = activations[0].reshape((784,1))

    # initialise z
    z = [
        np.zeros((16,1)),
        np.zeros((16,1)),
        np.zeros((10,1)),
    ]

    # FEEDFORWARD 
    for l in [0, 1, 2]: # l here is (l_index - 1) since thats how things are stored in other arrays
        a_l = activations[l]
        w_l = w[0][l]
        b_l = w[1][l]

        z[l] = np.matmul(w_l, a_l) + b_l

        activations[l+1] = sigmoid(z[l])  
        # here we actually did find lth layer's z, a 

    # OUTPUT ERROR
    del_C_wrt_a = ideal_output.reshape((10,1)) - activations[3]  # from defn

    # initialise deltas
    deltas = [
        np.zeros((16, 1)),
        np.zeros((16, 1)),
        np.zeros((10, 1))
    ]

    deltas[2] = del_C_wrt_a * sigmoid_prime(z[2]) # last layer

    # BACKPROPOGATION
    for l in [1, 0]:  # here l is (l_index - 1)
        w_next_l = w[0][l+1]
        deltas[l] = np.matmul(w_next_l.T, deltas[l+1]) * sigmoid_prime(z[l])
    
    return deltas  # 3 rows for each layer

def train_dataset(train_images, train_labels, activations, w, lr):
    m = len(train_images)
    deltas = [] # has deltas array for each training sample (yeah deltas in deltas)

    # getting deltas for each training sample
    for i in range(m):
        deltas.append(train_example(train_images[i], activations, w, train_labels[i]))

    # gradient descent
    for l in [3, 2, 1]:
        sum_d_a = np.zeros((w[0][l-1].shape)) 
        sum_d = np.zeros(w[1][l-1].shape)

        ####################### FINDING SUMS #####################################
        for i in range(m):  # for each training example
            sum_d_a += np.matmul(deltas[i][l-1], activations[l-1].T)
            sum_d   += deltas[i][l-1]  # our lth layer is computer's (l-1)th index

        w[0][l-1] -= (lr / m) * sum_d_a 
        w[1][l-1] -= (lr / m) * sum_d

# test NN
def test_nn(test_inputs, test_labels, w, activations):
    count = 0
    total = len(test_inputs)

    for i in range(len(test_inputs)):
        activations[0] = test_inputs[i]
        activations[0] = activations[0].reshape((784,1))

        z = [
            np.zeros((16,1)),
            np.zeros((16,1)),
            np.zeros((10,1)),
        ]

        for l in [0, 1, 2]: 
            a_l = activations[l]
            w_l = w[0][l]
            b_l = w[1][l]
            
            z[l] = np.matmul(w_l, a_l) + b_l

            activations[l+1] = sigmoid(z[l])

        if np.argmax(activations[3]) == np.argmax(test_labels[i]):
            count += 1

    print(f"accuracy = {count*100 / total}% i.e. {count} out of {total}")

# final output
def one_hot_encode(labels):
    result = np.zeros((labels.shape[0], 10))
    for i, label in enumerate(labels):
        result[i, label] = 1
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    activations, w = init_vars()

    train_labels = one_hot_encode(train_labels)
    test_labels = one_hot_encode(test_labels)

    for _ in range(5):
        # generate a permutation of indices
        perm = np.random.permutation(len(train_images))

        # use the permutation to shuffle both arrays
        train_images = train_images[perm]
        train_labels = train_labels[perm]
            
        # split the dataset into 10 parts
        num_parts = 10
        part_size = len(train_images) // num_parts
        parts = [train_images[i*part_size:(i+1)*part_size] for i in range(num_parts)]
        label_parts = [train_labels[i*part_size:(i+1)*part_size] for i in range(num_parts)]

        for i in range(num_parts):
            # use each part of the dataset in each iteration

            train_dataset(parts[i], label_parts[i], activations, w, lr=0.01)
            test_nn(test_images, test_labels, w, activations)
```

These are some of the outputs:

```
accuracy = 9.87% i.e. 987 out of 10000
accuracy = 9.88% i.e. 988 out of 10000
accuracy = 9.87% i.e. 987 out of 10000
accuracy = 9.87% i.e. 987 out of 10000
accuracy = 9.88% i.e. 988 out of 10000
accuracy = 9.87% i.e. 987 out of 10000
accuracy = 9.87% i.e. 987 out of 10000
accuracy = 9.85% i.e. 985 out of 10000
accuracy = 9.83% i.e. 983 out of 10000
```

Also, let me know if you need to see other parts of the code to help diagnose the issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The issue is likely due to the nested for-loop in the train_dataset() function that updates the weights using the backpropagation algorithm. This loop calculates the sums of the gradients for each weight in each layer over all training examples and then updates the weights using the average gradient.